# How should I be associating Core Data entities for use with RestKit?

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, restkit

I have two Core Data entities (`Client` and `UserFile`) that I have successfully set up a relationship between.

I have created classes for both entities, and made them subclasses of `RKManagedObject`.

When I create a new `UserFile`, I want to correctly associate it with a `Client`. Here's what I'm doing:

```
Client *client = [Client objectWithPrimaryKeyValue:@"1"];
UserFile *file = [UserFile object];
file.client = client;
file.clientId = client.clientId;
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:file delegate:self];
```

It seems like I have to assign `file.clientId` so that the correct parameter is sent to the server (if I only assign `file.client` then the submitted `client_id` is blank).

It seems like I have to assign `file.client` to prevent a new, empty `Client` from being created and associated with the file (the client relationship is required).

Is this correct? Do I really have to assign both the foreign key and the actual entity? This seems a bit redundant to me, but I'll happily admit that my Core Data and RestKit knowledge is lacking!

Comment: could you maybe post edit the question and add your - (NSDictionary*)elementToPropertyMappings implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your question, it looks like you do need to to both steps at the moment. Here's the code from the [RKDiscussionBoardExample](https://github.com/RestKit/RKDiscussionBoard) included with the library:

```
DBTopic* topic = [[DBTopic findFirstByAttribute:@"topicID" withValue:topicID] retain];
_post = [[DBPost object] retain];
_post.topicID = topic.topicID;
_post.topic = topic;
```

So either the relationships aren't set up properly in the example, or you really do need both steps.

Also, you should be using the newest version of RestKit which has a different object mapper and deprecates RKManagedObject. Your relationships should look something like this:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping* clientMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass: [Client class]];
clientMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"clientID";
[clientMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
@"id", @"clientID",
nil];

RKManagedObjectMapping* userFileMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UserFile class]];
userFileMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"userFileID";
[userFileMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
 @"id", @"userFileID",
 @"client_id", @"clientID",
 nil];

[userFileMapping mapRelationship:@"client" withObjectMapping:clientMapping];
```